# Pidyon Haben and Convert Parents

Tags: pidyon-haben

A Jewish boy who is the firstborn of his mother and who is born of a natural birth (no Caesarean section) needs to be redeemed. Since the redemption is to exempt him from the priestly duties, does the son of a convert (male or female) need to go through the process of pidyon haben?

Comment: Neither the firstborn son of a convert nor of any other non-priest (Yisrael/Levi) may perform the priestly duties, whether redeemed or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question could use some clarification, but, if you're asking whether the firstborn son of a Giyoret requires Pidyon, the answer is yes, even if she conceived before converting.
Shulchan Aruch, Yoreh Deah 305:20
הַשִּׁפְחָה שֶׁנִּשְׁתַּחְרְרָה וְכוּתִית שֶׁנִּתְגַיְּרָה כְּשֶׁהֵן מְעֻבָּרוֹת, וְיָלְדוּ, אַף עַל פִּי שֶׁהוֹרָתוֹ שֶׁלֹּא בִּקְדֻשָּׁה, הוֹאִיל וְנוֹלַד בִּקְדֻשָּׁה חַיָּב, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר: פֶּטֶר רֶחֶם בְּיִשְׂרָאֵל (בַּמִּדְבָּר ג, יב) וַהֲרֵי פָּטְרוּ רֶחֶם בְּיִשְׂרָאֵל. אֵין יָדוּעַ אִם קֹדֶם שֶׁנִּתְגַיְּרָה אוֹ אַחַר שֶׁנִּתְגַיְּרָה, הַמּוֹצִיא מֵחֲבֵרוֹ עָלָיו הָרְאָיָה.